# Is there anything better than server side datatable for handling large dataset

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, datatables

My table contains 25+ columns and rows are not limited.

All records come my client's daily usage.

Server side datatable is slowing down with only 100 rows.

Is there anything which can increase the speed of server side datatable or anything which can work better than datatable?

I am using **CodeIgniter** (php).

*This is my current code:*

```
var ETable = $('#example1').dataTable({
                "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy",
                "processing": true,
                "bSort": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "URL",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100], [10, 25, 50,100]],
                "sSortAsc": [[1, 'desc']],
                "iDisplayLength": 10,   
                "dom": 'Zlfrtip',
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                "sInfoFiltered": "",
                "sProcessing": "img/loading.gif'>"
                },
                "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }
        })
```

Comment: Proper Indexing in mysql solved my issue.